# SharePoint Online List: How to sort the lookup column's drop down list options?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

There are two Lists: *ListA* and *ListStatus*

*ListA* has a lookup field *Status* pointing to list *ListStatus*

In list *ListStatus* there are 3 items:
*New, WIP, Closed*

Currently, when creating a new *ListA* item, select *Status* field and the values in the drop down list show in below order:
[image]

Is it possible to show/sort the statuses in the drop down list as below? How?

- *New*
- *WIP*
- *Closed*

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Workaround, create a order in ListStatus list and add it to lookup show field.

Demo result.

[image]

[image]

Otherwise, you have to consider custom solution.

Comment: Hi Lee, thanks for your reply, but what I want to sort is the values in the drop down list of field *Status*, not the list view, have added a image in my question, please check out.

Comment: For classic view, use jslink to custom field render, https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a. for modern view, need SPFx extension https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/guidance/migrate-from-jslink-to-spfx-extensions

Comment: I have the same problem, unfortunately, there is no solution ?